# TFTP on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, iar

I am using TFTP service to get/put files from an embedded board(IAR systems). This used to be working file with windows XP, however with windows 7 the tftp service doesn't work. I have confirmed network connection between windos 7 machine and the board by opening web pages, telnet etc, which works well.

So, when I try to put some file using TFTP I can see a file craeted on the board(flash memory), however, the file is empty and the connection times out. It seems it reaches there but then nothing happens. I have turned off windows firewall as well. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

May be this would be usefu to someone:

In windows 7 you need to go to:

Control panel >> System and Security >> Allow a program through windows firewall >> Add the program(tftp) and make sure all three boxes are checked.

So, it is certainly firewall issue in windows 7 as I couldn't disable firewall this was the option I optedand worked.

Answer (score 1):

TFTP uses port 69 to establish a request but then communicates the response on a different and random port. This is why you have to allow tftp by application instead of port. This allows the Windows firewall to create the exceptions on the fly as needed by the application.

Comment: OP says he's already turned off the windows firewall and it didn't help.  I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also seem to have timeout issues when using TFTP, but eventually works after trying 10 different times. Make sure you disable any sort of anti-virus on Windows 7 system.

-Tony

Answer (score 0):

One problem I experienced was because of not having admin privileges. So, basically you right click on the icon and run as administrator and it solves the problem.

About connection timeout, sometimes I close it and open it again and it works.